# App in Background : task stopped

Tags: ios, iphone, background, nsoperation

My app while in background receive pushes to trigger some background tasks, scheduled in a NSOperationQueue.

The first NSOperation terminates correctly, but the second doesn't terminate, it seems like the task is paused, and when I put the app back in foreground the operation can terminate like it should.

Is there restrictions for background tasks ?  (The tasks take about 2 or 3 seconds to execute)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have enable any of the background service like Location , Background fetch , Remote Notification to enable active your app in background mode. Please below apple link where you may get more idea -

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Theses capabilities are already turned on. besides, the first operation can run.

Comment: you will be get 180 sec to perform your background task or renew it. I think due to background time expired and your application exit from background mode

Comment: But the first tasks only last 2 secs, and the second one stop at 1sec